# Application with monthly subscription

Tags: ios, app-store, subscriptions

I have built an app that I want to put on the store for free, yet I would like users to pay, say $1.00 per month to use the application continuosy, yet Apple's subscription documentation seems to apply only to magazine type application subscriptions. Does anyone know if this platform is applicable to non-publication type apps?

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole wealth of information on the official docs on how you could achieve this using [in-app purchases](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html), it's certainly not just limited to the Newsstand subscription model. After a user's month has expired, prevent them from accessing content in the app (up to you whether that means ALL content or just 'premium content') unless they buy another month. Apple would likely allow this since they get their cut of the on-going profits (They allow The New York Times Crossword Puzzle app to do this I read elsewhere).

Bear in mind though, your app would need to have some killer entertainment-value or usefulness in order for that business model to succeed!